# WebElement or WebDriver to invoke findElement method?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

What is the difference if we invoke the findElement method using WebElement or WebDriver? Do each of them has advantage over the other? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference of `findElement` between `WebElement` and `WebDriver` is the context.

Whereas the context of `WebDriver`is the current page, the context of `WebElement` is that element. `WebDriver` will search across the whole document, while `WebElement` will try to find the first child element from that node.

Note that when searching with `WebElement` via XPath, starting with `//` will still search across the entire document, not just the children of the current node. You can use `.//` to limit the search results to the children of that `WebElement`.